# How to tile background from a mid-screen position, one direction only, to fill to bottom of window (regardless of window height)?

Tags: html, css

I have a tricky CSS situation which I can't seem to solve.

I'd like the top portion of the body background to be one color (white), and then fill with another color (blue) from a certain position downward (below a footer in my case), and ensure that this color always fills (bleeds) to the bottom edge of of the browser window, regardless of window size.

I tried using a small blue bitmap, specifying the starting position via `background-position`, then applying `background-repeat: repeat-y`, but it fills in both directions.

I also thought of creating a long div but this affects the canvas size -- browser adds scroll bars, mobile will render the entire size -- no good.

Any ideas? (I'm not looking for a sticky footer) Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you set the background color on the footer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add the `background` property in your `footer` instead.

Then you add some huge `padding-bottom` and add a negative `margin-bottom` of the same amount.

Just make sure you have an outter `div` with `overflow: hidden;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e2JPP/3/)**

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the answer to a different question? I don't see the link between your code and the question posed by Pete.

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry, I forgot to add the fix for his question... It should be there now ;)

Comment: Oh, nevermind... that screwed up things a bit... Let me fix that a bit more :)

Comment: :big-grin: Thought something must have gone amiss. ;-)

Comment: @enhzflep should be fixed now :P

Comment: and for the last time... fixed properly now :rolleyes: Should be `min-height` instead of `height` on that outter div.

Comment: :chuckle: Happens to the best of us. hehe. :)

Comment: @Giovanni: Thanks. Seems to work in your Fiddle but not in my project.. getting a super-long page scroll.. may need to re-construct step by step. My footer has some absolute overlays, so perhaps that's the issue. I'm not quite understanding the application of 100% height and min-height here..

Comment: On a related note, how is the footer done here on Stack Overflow? If I drag down on the bottom of the window, it keeps getting pulled down with it. If I do that in my case, the footer stays put while a gap is opening up. I'd be happy with the SO solution, as an alternative. I see they have a 'vertical-align' set to 'baseline' but that doesn't seem to do it for me either..

Comment: @pete you need to set a div to wrap all your content (just after `<body>`) and set it to `min-height:100%` and `overflow:hidden`. Make sure your `body` and `html` tags have `height:100%` set...